# Getting windows special folder in code when provided by a user

Tags: c#, windows

Let's say a user specified a path in a config file like %temp%.  I can get there by typing %temp% in the address bar.

However, if I want to get there with a C# program, the only way I see to get there is with http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.getfolderpath.aspx.

Is it possible to resolve a user specified path like %temp% or %userprofile%/local inside the C# code itself?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use [`Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.expandenvironmentvariables.aspx) to expand all variables in the path. Don't forget that if this is a service, services usually run under a different user.

Comment: @iseletsky If this answer was what you were looking for, you should consider [accepting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/213634) it as the correct answer, by clicking in its check mark.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable`. One [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/77zkk0b6.aspx):

```
// Change the directory to %WINDIR%
Environment.CurrentDirectory = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("windir");
DirectoryInfo info = new DirectoryInfo(".");
lock(info)
{      
  Console.WriteLine("Directory Info:   "+info.FullName);
}
```